# is end-point included in uniform function of the random module?

Tags: python, random, module, range

```
import random
print(random.uniform(1,3))
```

'is 3 included in the range or not,and how is it decided whether to include the end-point 3 in the range or not?
floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random().
How is the above equation solved?'

Comment: It's hard to be any more definitive on a question like this than the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform):

random.uniform(a, b): Return a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.

In this case, 3 would be included in the range.